# Create pairs with 2 array, so that there is no repeated pairs?

Tags: php, php-7

I'm trying to create a script to create pairs from 2 different arrays. For example I have two array given below:

```
<?php
    //Array 1
    $arr1 = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
    //Array 2
    $arr2 = array('X', 'Y', 'Z');
```

And I need output in such a manner so that it match with each element and didn't repeat pair and sequence also. Here is expected output:

```
$output = array(
  0 => array('A', 'X'),
  1 => array('B', 'Y'),
  2 => array('C', 'Z'),
  3 => array('D', 'X'),
  4 => array('A', 'Y'),
  5 => array('B', 'Z'),
  6 => array('C', 'X'),
  7 => array('D', 'Y'),
  8 => array('A', 'Z'),
  9 => array('B', 'X'),
  10 => array('C', 'Y'),
  11 => array('D', 'Z')
)
```

**Note: 2 arrays can differ with number of count and values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Could be achieved with

```
//Array 1
$arr1 = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
//Array 2
$arr2 = array('X', 'Y', 'Z');

$output = array();

foreach($arr1 as $i1){
    foreach ($arr2 as $i2) {
        $output[] = array($i1, $i2);
    }
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

If you want the output to be in the same order as you have mentioned above, following should do that.

```
$newoutput = array();

$x = 0;
$y = 0;
for($i = 1; $i <= (count($arr1) * count($arr2)); $i++){
    $newoutput[] = array($arr1[($x % count($arr1))], $arr2[($y % count($arr2))]);
    $x++;
    $y++;
}

echo "<br />", json_encode($newoutput);
```

Output however, is a different order of the same output as previous.

**EDIT**

The second works only when `(count($arrX) % count($arrY)) > 0`.

Comment: Hi Romeo, you code work's fine but check your code with this array as it is repeating `$arr1 = array('X', 'Y');
    $arr2 = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'J', 'K');`. Thanks!

Comment: I have fixed that and also thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: @AjayKumar If you wish, you can update this question to reflect your refinement so that anyone who reads this in the future would be benefited... :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built in support for that.
You need to loop the arrays nested and build a result array.

```
$arr1 = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
$arr2 = array('X', 'Y', 'Z');

foreach($arr1 as $item1){
    foreach($arr2 as $item2){
        $res[] = [$item1, $item2];
    }
}

var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/CdE8Q

Answer (score 0):

Try This out (This will sort out the same pair if found):

```
//Array 1
$arr1 = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'E'); // Same element will be sort out in pair
//Array 2
$arr2 = array('X', 'Y', 'Z' , 'X', 'Y', 'X'); // Same element will be sort out in pair
$output = array();
$used_pair = array(); // Keeping used pair
$i = 1;
foreach ($arr1 as $each1) {
    foreach ($arr2 as $each2) {
        if (!in_array($each1.$each2, $used_pair)) {
            $output[] = array($each1, $each2);
            $used_pair[] = $each1 . $each2;
        }
    }
}
print_r($used_pair); // array with pair string
print_r($output); // array with pair array
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

this is an example that ouputs unique values in the same order :

online eval : https://3v4l.org/H2pad

```
<?php

function cartesian(array $x,array $y): array
{
    $result = [];
    $size = count($x) * count($y);
    $posX = 0;
    $posY = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        if (!isset($x[$posX])) {
            $posX = 0;
        } elseif(!isset($y[$posY])) {
            $posY = 0;
        }
        $result[] = [$x[$posX],$y[$posY]];
        $posX++; $posY++;
    }
    return $result;
}

$x = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');

$y = array('X', 'Y', 'Z');

print_r(cartesian($x,$y));
```

( tbh, it took me a lot of rubber duck debugging )